# Count value in template expression

Tags: templates, xtend

I want to count a value inside a template expression, in Xtend, without printing it out.

This is my code:

```
def generateTower(Tower in) {
    var counter = 0.0;
'''
One         Two             Three           Four
«FOR line : in.myTable»
«counter»   «line.val1»     «line.val2»     «line.val3»
«counter = counter + 1»
«ENDFOR»
'''
    }
```

So this will generate a table with four columns, whereas the first column is incremented starting at 0.0. The problem is, that `«counter = counter + 1»` is printed as well. But I want the expression above to just count up, without printing it out.

What could be the best solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this simple and readable solution:

```
«FOR line : in.myTable»
«counter++»   «line.val1»     «line.val2»     «line.val3»
«ENDFOR»
```

If you insist on the separate *increment expression*, use a *block* with `null` value. This works because the `null` value is converted to empty string in *template expression*s (of course you could use `""` as well):

```
«FOR line : in.myTable»
«counter»   «line.val1»     «line.val2»     «line.val3»
«{counter = counter + 1; null}»
«ENDFOR»
```

Although the first solution is the better. If you require complex logic in a *template expression* I recommend implementing it by *method*s not by inline code...

And finally, here is a more OO solution for the problem:

```
class TowerGenerator {
    static val TAB = "\t"

    def generateTower(Tower in) {
        var counter = 0

        '''
            One«TAB»Two«TAB»Three«TAB»Four
            «FOR line : in.myTable»
                «generateLine(line, counter++)»
            «ENDFOR»
        '''
    }

    def private generateLine(Line line, int lineNumber) '''
        «lineNumber»«TAB»«line.val1»«TAB»«line.val2»«TAB»«line.val3»
    '''
}
```

Comment: `«{counter = counter + 1; null}»` did the trick: Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xtend is a full-fledged programming language. You can write Java-like expressions and templates. The problem there is that you're inside a triple quote (template), and everything you write there gets outputted. You can count inside the loop, but take into account that you're counting the elements in the `in.myTable` collection, and this can be obtained using `in.myTable.length`. So `count` could be calculated beforehand as `in.myTable.length`.

Answer (score 0):

`«{counter = counter + 1; null}»` definitely worked. But as a recommendation, since it is java, writing it as `«{counter++; null}»` should do the trick as well. It helps because, you may need to modify your code and you can also put it in front as in: `++counter` - by putting the operator first, the compiler takes a number, adds one to it before reading the value.